# Pi 4: No Composite Video Out

Tags: pi-4, composite-video

I have a Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2. I'm unable to get the composite video out to function.

I *think* I have enabled the composite video out and set up NTSC 4:3 correctly by including the following in my config.txt, but still no picture:

```
sdtv_mode=0
sdtv_aspect=1
enable_tvout=1
```

I have also set Enable composite (6 -> A8 -> V2) in raspi-config.

Verified working:

- NTSC CRT TV
- Coaxaial cable
- Composite to RF converter
- 3.5mm to composite cable

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Full config.txt**

```
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# composite mode: 0 = NTSC
sdtv_mode=0

# composite aspect ratio: 1 = 4:3
sdtv_aspect=1

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Enable composite output
enable_tvout=1

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Comment: how do you know that the RPi is not outputting composite video?

Answer (score 1):

It was the cable ‍♂️

Do not buy: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ZNTP4RW/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_DX98MT96XG87XVV3S7X7?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZNTP4RW)